Using AnnotationPluginImplKt in AndroidStudio
enter image description her
I saw a Mapbox Java tutorial on Youtube, there is a step that they use "AnnotationPluginImplKt".I had imported:
implementation ("com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.15.2");
implementation ("com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.17.1")
but AnnotationPluginImplKt is still not available. Anyone can tell me where I can import that or any other way to fix it in Java Android, thank you!
mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri(Style.SATELLITE, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                mapView.getMapboxMap().setCamera(new CameraOptions.Builder().zoom(20.0).build());
                locationComponentPlugin.setEnabled(true);
                locationComponentPlugin.setLocationProvider(navigationLocationProvider);
                getGestures(mapView).addOnMoveListener(onMoveListener);
                locationComponentPlugin.updateSettings(new Function1<LocationComponentSettings, Unit>() {
                    @Override
                    public Unit invoke(LocationComponentSettings locationComponentSettings) {
                        locationComponentSettings.setEnabled(true);
                        locationComponentSettings.setPulsingEnabled(true);
                        return null;
                    }
                });
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.location_pin);
                AnnotationPlugin annotationPlugin = AnnotationPluginImplKt.getAnnotations(mapView);
                PointAnnotationManager pointAnnotationManager = PointAnnotationManagerKt.createPointAnnotationManager(annotationPlugin, mapView);
                addOnMapClickListener(mapView.getMapboxMap(), new OnMapClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMapClick(@NonNull Point point) {
                        pointAnnotationManager.deleteAll();
                        PointAnnotationOptions pointAnnotationOptions = new PointAnnotationOptions().withTextAnchor(TextAnchor.CENTER).withIconImage(bitmap)
                                .withPoint(point);
                        pointAnnotationManager.create(pointAnnotationOptions);

                        setRoute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                fetchRoute(point);
                            }
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                focusLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        focusLocation = true;
                        getGestures(mapView).addOnMoveListener(onMoveListener);
                        focusLocationBtn.hide();
                    }
                });

                placeAutocompleteUiAdapter.addSearchListener(new PlaceAutocompleteUiAdapter.SearchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuggestionsShown(@NonNull List<PlaceAutocompleteSuggestion> list) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuggestionSelected(@NonNull PlaceAutocompleteSuggestion placeAutocompleteSuggestion) {
                        ignoreNextQueryUpdate = true;
                        focusLocation = false;
                        searchET.setText(placeAutocompleteSuggestion.getName());
                        searchResultsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        pointAnnotationManager.deleteAll();
                        PointAnnotationOptions pointAnnotationOptions = new PointAnnotationOptions().withTextAnchor(TextAnchor.CENTER).withIconImage(bitmap)
                                .withPoint(placeAutocompleteSuggestion.getCoordinate());
                        pointAnnotationManager.create(pointAnnotationOptions);
                        updateCamera(placeAutocompleteSuggestion.getCoordinate(), 0.0);

                        setRoute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                fetchRoute(placeAutocompleteSuggestion.getCoordinate());
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPopulateQueryClick(@NonNull PlaceAutocompleteSuggestion placeAutocompleteSuggestion) {
                        //queryEditText.setText(placeAutocompleteSuggestion.getName());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

Anyone can tell me where I can import that (AnnotationPluginImplKt) or any other way to fix it in Java Android, thank you!
